# Update label on every character entered

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a calculator like app. The app will have a to get inputs and display results instantly without having the users to press any button explicitly. So when ever the user wants to calculate any results say "123+321" then

**input --> output**

```
1 --> 1
12 --> 12
123 --> 123
123+ --> 123
123+3 --> 126
123+32 --> 155
123+321 --> 444
```

I have a function that will recognize the inputs and produce relevant outputs but i need to press a PushButton everytime when i want the output label to be updated. Any solution that can help me update that label on every change in the textbox.

Comment: use slots of the lineedit

Comment: thanks. slot named `on_lineedit_textChanged()` i am using and it is working perfectly as i wanted @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As eyllanesc mentioned in the comment that we can use slots. There is a slot called `textChanged` that can be used to execute a function for every change in the `editline` textbox
Right click on the `editline` and select `go to slot` and then select `textChanged` and you will be able to type your code to do required manipulations.

Comment: i just answered my question that we can use `on_editline_textChanged()` slot as you said.